# How is my book completing the square?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In my book I see:

> To integrate the given function we complete the square in the denominator:

$$4x^2 - 4x + 3 = (2x-1)^2 + 2$$

How is it doing this? When I complete the square I get:

$$x^2 - x + \frac{3}{4} = 0$$
$$x^2 - x + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{-1}{2}$$
$$\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{-1}{2}$$
$$x - \frac{1}{2} = \sqrt{\frac{-1}{2}}$$

now I'm stuck. can someone help to show me how my book gets the $(2x-1)^2 + 2$?

Comment: Why have you set the denominator equal to zero and divided through by 4? This is not a valid procedure.

Comment: @PeterForeman I thought that's how I complete the square...

Comment: @Jwan622 Completing the square is used in this case to simplify an expression, not to solve an equation. These are different procedures.

Comment: That's the method used for solving quadratic equations, which is something completely different.

Comment: This looks like a quadratic no?

Comment: Note that $(2a + b)^2 = 4a^2 + 4ab + b^2$.  In this case, $4a^2 = 4x^2$ and $4ab = -4x$, so $a = x$ and $b = -1$.  Hence, you want $4x^2 - 4x + 3 = 4x^2 - 4x + 1 + 2 = (2x - 1)^2 + 2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$4x^2-4x+3=4x^2-4x+1+2=(2x-1)^2+2.$$

Comment: so this isn't really completing the square right?

Comment: Why not? I wrote your expression as a square plus a number that should be added so that the equality holds.

Answer (score 0):

$4x^2-4x+ 3 = 4x^2-4x +  1 + 2 =  (2x-1)^2+2$

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the same as the other answers, but I'll try to explain a bit more:

Given expression:
$$4x^2 - 4x + 3$$
$$=4\left(x^2-x+\frac{3}{4}\right)$$
$$=4\left((x^2)-2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)(x)+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}\right)$$
$$=4\left(\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}\right)$$
$$=4\left(\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
$$=4\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+2$$
$$=4\left(\frac{2x-1}{2}\right)^2+2$$
$$=(2x-1)^2+2$$

Because this expression is in the denominator of the integrand, we can further express this as
$$(2x-1)^2+(\sqrt2)^2$$
And proceed with the integration, depending on the expression in the numerator.